# Что я делаю не так? В чём проблема?

Tags: c#

Есть такой код:

```
public static bool InjectDLL(Process process, string strDLLName)
        {
            IntPtr ptr2;
            uint num2;
            UIntPtr ptr5;
            IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
            int num = strDLLName.Length + 1;
            IntPtr lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, (uint) num, 0x3000, 4);
            VirtualProtect(lpAddress, (uint) num, 4, out num2);
            WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpAddress, strDLLName, (UIntPtr) num, out ptr2);
            UIntPtr procAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
            IntPtr handle = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, 0, procAddress, lpAddress, 0, out ptr5);
            switch (WaitForSingleObject(handle, 0xbb8))
            {
                case 0x80L:
                case 0x102L:
                case 0xffffffffL:
                    CloseHandle(handle);
                    return false;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpAddress, (UIntPtr) 0, 0x8000);
            CloseHandle(handle);
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            return true;
        }
```

На это:

```
            case 0x80L:
            case 0x102L:
            case 0xffffffffL:
```

говорит типа:

```
Ошибка  2   Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "long" в "int". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов)  C:\Users\user\Desktop\Trainer\memorygame\PrivilegeManager.cs    119 22  Trainer
```

Что делать?Буду благодарен.

Comment: В case у вас стоят long, а ответ приходит в int, видимо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте явное преобразование в long:

```
switch ((long)WaitForSingleObject(handle, 0xbb8))
{
    case 0x80L:
    case 0x102L:
    ...
```